# Nav highlight current page

Tags: html, angularjs, css, nav

Please help solve the problem, because my ideas have been exhausted...(

*I have a :*

```
<nav class="nav_editor" ng-show="status.editorMenuOn">
            <ul class="menu_editor">
                <li class=""><a ng-href="/articles/user/{{ status.userID }}">My Articles</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="/articles">Create Article</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Comments</a></li>
            </ul>
</nav>
```

*And a CSS classes:*

```
.menu_editor li a {
color: rgb(125,125,125);
font-size: 1.25vw;
margin-right: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

I want to make highlighting the item in the menu when this page is active (not pseudo ":active"), just when someone watching current page, for example "My Articles".

I have tried about 3 variants by CSS/HTML only, JavaScript and jQuery, but it is either not working properly or not working at all.

Please help solve this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the myArticle page loads, just do jquery addClass method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //remove highlighted menu buttons on pageload
     $(".menu_editor li").removeClass("activeMenuItem");

     //add class only to the specific one
     $(".foo").addClass("activeMenuItem");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, i edit code a little bit and it works, but it works for every links in menu at the same time (does not matter page is active or not) , probably because of the Angular.

Comment: Have you included jquery file? Because its working for me.

Comment: Youp, sure

Edited HTML code for <nav> but now the class is applied to all <a> in the <nav>

Comment: And mostly this is because of Angular, i use ng-show to add the menu in the page I needed, and because of this can be conflicts

Comment: Try adding each <li> element its own class (tab1, tab2, tab3). And replace the ".foo" (in upper code) with "tab class" (example: myArticle is tab1)